# Adding a row with children to a source model does not display correctly on a filtered proxy model

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I appended to the source model a row (called `Something`) that has children and I can expand the item to see its children but when a filter is applied, the filtered item does not appear to be expandable.

[image: Unfiltered]

[image: FIltered]

```
self.sf_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
self.treeview.setModel(self.sf_proxy_model)
treeview_model = QStandardItemModel()
...defining source model for TreeView...

self.sf_proxy_model.setSourceModel(treeview_model)
```

Filter implementation:

```
def filter_regex_changed(self):
    syntax = QRegExp.PatternSyntax(QRegExp.RegExp)
    regexp = '^{}'.format(self.lineedit_quickfilter.text())
    regexp = QRegExp(regexp, Qt.CaseInsensitive, syntax)
    self.sf_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp(regexp)
```

Here's the function that creates the row:

```
def create_pin_group(self, group):
    model = self.treeview.model()
    model_source = self.treeview.model().sourceModel()

    # Get child names from a list widget
    filtered_pins = self.listview.model()
    filtered_pins_text = []

    for row in range(filtered_pins.rowCount()):
        item = filtered_pins.index(row, 0)
        filtered_pins_text.append(item.data(Qt.DisplayRole))

    # Create a new group (row) and populate with filtered pins
    row_name = QStandardItem(group['name'])

    row_color = QStandardItem('')
    row_color.setData(group['color'], Qt.UserRole)
    row_color.setBackground(QColor(group['color']))
    row_color.setEditable(False)

    row_group = QStandardItem(group['name'])
    row_group.setEditable(False)

    row_type = QStandardItem(group['type'])
    row_type.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    row_coupling_net = QStandardItem('')
    row_coupling_net.setEditable(False)

    row_data = [None] * model_source.columnCount()
    row_data[self.column_name] = row_name
    row_data[self.column_color] = row_color
    row_data[self.column_group] = row_group
    row_data[self.column_type] = row_type
    row_data[self.column_coupling_net] = row_coupling_net

    for pin in filtered_pins_text:
        child_data = [None] * model_source.columnCount()
        child_data[self.column_name] = QStandardItem(pin)
        child_data[self.column_color] = row_color.clone()
        child_data[self.column_group] = QStandardItem(group['name'])
        child_data[self.column_type] = row_type.clone()
        child_data[self.column_coupling_net] = QStandardItem('')

        row_name.appendRow(child_data)

    model_source.appendRow(row_data)

    # Delete pins from source model
    for pin in filtered_pins_text:
        item = model_source.findItems(pin, Qt.MatchRecursive, self.column_name)[0]
        parent = item.parent()

        if parent.row() == -1:  # Single pins
            model_source.takeRow(item.row())

        else:
            if parent.rowCount() == 1:  # One child remaining, delete entire last row
                model_source.takeRow(parent.row())

            else:
                parent.takeRow(item.row())

    model.sort(self.column_group, Qt.AscendingOrder)
    model_source.sort(self.column_group, Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you implement filtering in your filter model? Maybe no child contains `Something`?

Comment: It looks like your `sf_proxy_model` applies `regexp` to the value of `Name` column for each item (including its children). That is if array `filtered_pins_text` does not contain any string which begins with the characters `Something` then the filtered item will not contain any child.

Comment: @olya That makes sense now. When I created that group there were no children containing `Something`. How do I set the proxy model to filter only top-level items or show the parent item if the pattern matches the children?